# What does negative energy imply?

Tags: energy

I know energy comes in a number of forms and every form of energy is defined uniquely.

But if I had to give a broad definition of energy, I would define it as "ability of a system to perform work."

Using the above definition doesn't make any sense while trying to explain negative energy. So what does negative energy mean?

Comment: are you asking about classical negative energy, such as negative potential energy, or about something more exotic resulting, for instance, from negative mass or other kinds of exotic matter?

Comment: There is only one definition of energy and you got it. It's the ability to perform work.

Comment: @bruce I am asking about the negetive magnitude of energy as in potential energy.

Comment: 'Energy is the ability to do work' implies that work is a more primitive idea that has already been defined.   Unless you say that energy is work, in which case it's tautology.   I think I'd rather have 'energy' as the primitive and define work as something that energy does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If positive work is "work done by the system" then negative work is just "work done *on* the system". The sign just tells if energy is added to the system or leaving the system.

Answer (score 2):

An nice example complementing Steeven's answer is the [energy levels of the hydrogen atom](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/hyde.html#c2).

The energy of a hydrogen atom is given by $E_n=-\frac{13.6eV}{n^2}$, where $n=1,2,3...$ (the Principal Quantum Number $n$).

The ground state (lowest possible energy) is $E_1=-13.6 eV$ (for $n=1$). A higher state of energy would be (for example) $E_3=-1.5eV$ (for $n=3$).

To 'kick' the atom from $n=1$ to $n=3$ the following amount of energy is required:

$\Delta E=E_3-E_1$, or $\Delta E=-1.5eV-(-13.6eV)=+12.1eV$.

So the difference between two negative energies is positive here: we need to put in energy to go from $n=1$ to $n=3$.